# Return data from function to ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I wanted to make a button when I clicked it called that ajax function to send data to a function then the function returns the data back to the ajax so that it can execute the success call which makes the button become disabled.

Here's the function `notify()`

```
public function notify()
{

    $id = $this->user['id'];

    $agent = AffiliateAgents::get($id);
    if (empty($agent)) redirect('affiliate/sales/browse');

    $_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);

    $agent = [
        'commission_claim' => 1

    ];

    AffiliateAgents::update($id, $agent);
    $status = AffiliateAgents::get($id ,'commission_claim');

    return $status;
}
```

Here's the ajax

```
$("#notify").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'affiliate/sales/notify',
            success: function() {
            showNotification("success", "Berjaya!", "Anda berjaya membuat tuntutan komisyen");
        }

    });

    })
```

Comment: Is this core PHP or any framework?

Comment: this is framework sir

Comment: Please mentioned that framework in the tag that you able to get right answer.

Comment: sorry sir, i forget to tag framework as well

Comment: No, my dear name means Laravel or CodeIgniter etc.

Comment: im using homemade framework

Answer (score 0):

You can get the returned data (from **PHP**) like this:

```
//In the ajax...
success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
```

> **success** 
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR
>   ) A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: So if i wanted my function to return the $status data from the function to the ajax i gotta write $status on the success function?

Comment: No, just do what I write... the (php) `return $status` will be given in the `function(data)`, so you can use data inside **success**

Comment: Use this `console.log(data)` to check what's returning.

Answer (score 0):

just pass parameter into success function in this line:
`...
success: function(yourData) {
...`

Comment: So if i wanted my function to return the $status data from the function to the ajax i gotta write $status on the success function?

Comment: no the name of the parameter can be anything just don't put `$` inf front of the variable name (since it's javascript).
So in your case it could ba name `status`. You can try to log it out like so:
```...
success: function(status) {
      console.log(status)
    }
...```

Comment: so on the notify() am i doing it correctly in terms of returning back the data to the ajax call?

Comment: php code in notify() seems OK, if you are not completely sure, you can also check that there are some data that you return from php `echo $status`

Comment: im writing the function inside a controller php page so i couldnt check using echo

Comment: I manage to find out the value of $status by var_dump but it seems that it doesnt return back to the ajax after the whole process end inside the notify() function

Comment: For testing purposes create notify() function something like this:
`
public function notify()
{
    $status = 'Test data as a string;
    return $status;
}
`
So you can now focus only on frontend part (JS/ajax).

Comment: i try it and it doesnt send back data to ajax

Comment: check other stuff then, if the url endpoint in ajax call is correct
```url: 'affiliate/sales/notify',```

Comment: yes, i can assure the url is correct because when i clicked the button it direct to the function and do operations inside the function where it involve with the database and yes it send the data in the database as well so the URL is functioning

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted to disable the buttons after the success of Ajax.
You have to write the following code

in ajax part

```
    success : function(data){
     // disable button
     if(data="success"){
       $("#buttonId").attr("disabled","disabled");
     } else{
       alert("Status not success");
     }
}
```